# Using react, I have no idea why fetch or axios always return two array from API

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, fetch-api

[image: this is my sample]

My code is this below.
Although I expect one array return from API, it always show two arrays, each field with 10 users in console.

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
};
fetchData();
```

Comment: Can you show what you get in that console.log? I've tested that code and I see one array

Comment: Run that code - it shows only one array. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It seems like you are using fetchData in useEffect, in react strictMode useEFfect with empty dependency runs twice in development mode.  thats why you are seeing two datas in the console..